# Group a data frame by quartiles of an individual variable contained in the data frame

Tags: r, aggregate

I have the *swiss* data set provided by R, which has the following form:

```
            Fertility Agriculture Examination Education Catholic Infant.Mortality
Courtelary       80.2        17.0          15        12     9.96             22.2
Delemont         83.1        45.1           6         9    84.84             22.2
Franches-Mnt     92.5        39.7           5         5    93.40             20.2
    .              .           .            .         .      .                 . 
    .              .           .            .         .      .                 . 
    .              .           .            .         .      .                 . 

V. De Geneve     35.0         1.2          37        53    42.34             18.0
Rive Droite      44.7        46.6          16        29    50.43             18.2
Rive Gauche      42.8        27.7          22        29    58.33             19.3
```

And I would like to know if there is a simple or easy way to classify the data in four groups, one for each quartile of the *Education* variable and then get the corresponding *Infant.Mortality* for each province, so I can get something like:

```
       Group1stQ           Group1stQ           Group1stQ          Group1stQ 

   <Mortality for      <Mortality for       <Mortality for     <Mortality for
     1st province        1st province         1st province       1st province
     on this group>     on this group>       on this group>     on this group>

   <Mortality for      <Mortality for       <Mortality for     <Mortality for
     2nd province        2nd province         2nd province       2nd province
     on this group>     on this group>       on this group>     on this group>

   <Mortality for      <Mortality for       <Mortality for     <Mortality for
     3rd province        3rd province         3rd province       3rd province
     on this group>     on this group>       on this group>     on this group>
          .                  .                    .                  .
          .                  .                    .                  .
          .                  .                    .                  .
```

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Comment: To clarfiy, do you want the _average_ infant mortality for each quantile?

Comment: Sorry... I'll edit the question... that's not what I need... even I was confused... Im really sorry

Comment: I assume you meant the columns to be `Group1stQ           Group2ndQ        Group3rdQ          Group4thQ`? Is there more than one row for each location?

Comment: I don't understand the question. There is only one row per province in the data, right? So each province belongs to exactly one quartile of the Education. Where should the other numbers come from?

Comment: @cbeleites: You are right! you are helping me also with conceptual stuff... I'm really sorry, this is awkward... I've edited the question again. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about:

```
> swiss$qEdu <- cut (swiss$Education, 
                     breaks = quantile (swiss$Education, c (0, .25, .5, .75, 1)), 
                     include.lowest = TRUE)

> aggregate (swiss$Infant.Mortality, list (qEdu = swiss$qEdu), FUN = mean)
     qEdu        x
1   [1,6] 19.31429
2   (6,8] 21.93636
3  (8,12] 19.38182
4 (12,53] 19.30909
```

(I don't really know what your numbers are - they don't coincide with the averages I get)

(That was before the edit...)

(After 2nd edit:)
If you want the Infant.Mortality for each of the provinces belongig to that quartile of Eduction, use `list ()` as aggregation function:

```
>  aggregate (swiss$Infant.Mortality, list (qEdu = swiss$qEdu), FUN = list)
     qEdu                                                                                  x
1   [1,6] 20.2, 24.5, 18.7, 21.2, 22.4, 15.3, 21.0, 18.0, 15.1, 19.8, 18.3, 19.4, 20.2, 16.3
2   (6,8]                   20.3, 26.6, 23.6, 24.9, 21.0, 19.1, 20.0, 23.8, 22.5, 20.0, 19.5
3  (8,12]                   22.2, 22.2, 16.5, 22.7, 20.0, 18.0, 16.7, 16.3, 17.8, 20.3, 20.5
4 (12,53]                   20.6, 24.4, 20.2, 10.8, 20.9, 18.1, 18.9, 23.0, 18.0, 18.2, 19.3
```

or:

```
> Infant.Mortality <- lapply (levels (swiss$qEdu), function (x) swiss$Infant.Mortality [swiss$qEdu == x])
> names (Infant.Mortality) <- levels (swiss$qEdu)
> Infant.Mortality
$`[1,6]`
 [1] 20.2 24.5 18.7 21.2 22.4 15.3 21.0 18.0 15.1 19.8 18.3 19.4 20.2 16.3

$`(6,8]`
 [1] 20.3 26.6 23.6 24.9 21.0 19.1 20.0 23.8 22.5 20.0 19.5

$`(8,12]`
 [1] 22.2 22.2 16.5 22.7 20.0 18.0 16.7 16.3 17.8 20.3 20.5

$`(12,53]`
 [1] 20.6 24.4 20.2 10.8 20.9 18.1 18.9 23.0 18.0 18.2 19.3
```

Comment: Please read the edit and the other comment... I don't need the average, but to group the data like I say in the new question... I'm really sorry... Thanks four your help!

Comment: In the aggregate() approach, `x` (the second column) is the list of values of mortality for the corresponding quantile? if it is so, then that's exactly what I needed!!! Thank you very much! =)

Comment: yes. I aggregate Infant.Mortality by the factor giving the quartiles. And instead of calculating some summary value, I use the `list` function to get all those values.